# How to remove php extension from pages except search results?

Tags: php, htaccess, search

Using htaccess I have these php rules:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## don't touch /forum URIs
RewriteRule ^forums/ - [L,NC]

## hide .php extension snippet

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]

# To remove www header
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Everything is working, except if I do a search, the search results page is not showing the results because it is taking out the php extension.  Example: search/?s=building where "building" is the term used.  Generally, it should look like this: search.php?s=building

How do I tell htaccess that I only wanted to hide the php extensions of the pages except the results page?

Comment: I'm not sure why you would need the extension (and to make an exception) on the search URLs? Why does the search page not work when the other pages work OK - why is the search page any different? The point of doing this is presumably to remove the file extension from _all_ URLs. Does your page link to `search` or `search.php` (it should be the former).

Comment: The search page has an extension of .php but is taken out because of the htaccess rules.http://ogsantosconstruction.com/

Comment: In order to implement this correctly, all your internal links should be without the `.php` extension as well, otherwise all your navigation is going to result in an external redirect (2 requests) - which is what's happening.

Comment: ...Although this isn't directly related to your problem with the search.

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd want to do this. Search engines don't care which software powers your website, and most users wouldn't either. What's the goal?

Comment: The goal is to simply have a clean looking url / address.  Thank you for all the feedbacks! I will test, implement the solutions provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]
```

To exclude your "search" page from the redirect you could include an additional condition. Only redirect when the requested URL is not "search.php".

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s[^.]+\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !search\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

I've tweaked the rules a bit to make them more efficient by specifically checking for the ".php" file extension in the `RewriteRule`. Removed the `NC` flag as this seems redundant. Changed from `R` (temporary) to `R=301` (permanent) redirect - I presume this should be "permanent"? (Although it's good to test with a temporary - non-cached - redirect.)

However, why the "search" page doesn't work without the file extension would seem to be another issue. It should work! There seems to be another (301) redirect that is redirecting `/search?s=world` to `/search/?s=world`?

You also still need to resolve all your internal linking so that you link to URLs without the `.php` extension otherwise your site is going to be issuing a lot of unnecessary redirects.